# Getting data from another website with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just tried to load data from `www.somedomain.com`'s `#SomeText` Tag in #Data Tag with jQuery Ajax
I used :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Data").load('http://www.somedomain.com/index.html#SomeText');
    });
</script>
```

but webpage text doesn't load and in Google Chrome's JavaScript console I got this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.somedomain.com/index.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9154' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: you tried cross domain scripting ... read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS and google for "chrome Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: This might be due to cross domain access you may user cURL for this purpose.

Comment: If you run your html page on a web server it should work. If you are just running it locally then you will run into the the CORS issue.

Comment: I running in IIS Express